# How to make Dartium stop at a breakpoint?

Tags: dart, webstorm, dartium

dI am trying to get back into Dart programming after a year of break. When I last used Dart I use the DartEditor, which has since been deprecated. Now, I am trying to use WebStorm, and Dartium to run the standard dart project templates.

When I build the Uber Simple Web Application, I can get Webstorm to start the Dartium browser and display the page, but I cannot get it to stop at a breakpoint. When I build the Polymer Web Application, WebStorm starts the Dartium browser, but never displays the page - the request is made but nothing happens!

I can open the projects with a standard browser without an issue.

---

I have installed the JetBrains IDE Support plugin.

- Dartium version: 45.0.2454.104
- Webstorm version: 2016.1.1 bld 145.597
- Dart version: 1.16.0

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an issue in WebStorm that breaks showing applications in Dartium related to caching. The `pub serve` window in WebStorm should show on which port your application is served. if you open the URL in Dartium using this port

http://localhost:thePort/index.html

then it should work. 
An update containing a fix for this issue was announced for this week.

Comment: Dartium now runs, but the code does not stop at any breakpoints.

Comment: I guess it needs to be loaded through WebStorm for this to work. You will need to wait for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm 2016.1.2 and IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2 official releases are published now, all known problems regarding SDK 1.16 are fixed there.